# Finding transformation matrix using OpenCV

Tags: graphics, opencv, kinect

I have 2 sets of 3D points, also feature matching between the two sets, now I need to calculate the transformation matrix between the two images.
 Is there an opencv function that given 2 sets of 3D points will give the transformation matrix ?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need an affine transform, you could take a look at using the [estimateAffine3D](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=estimateaffine3d#int%20estimateAffine3D%28InputArray%20srcpt,%20InputArray%20dstpt,%20OutputArray%20out,%20OutputArray%20inliers,%20double%20ransacThreshold%20,%20double%20confidence%29) function provided by OpenCV.

It doesn't look like the have a standard sample I can point you toward for usage, but they do have a [unit test](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/tests/cv/src/affine3d_estimator.cpp?rev=2391) you might be interested in.

Comment: What if I want to estimate a more complex transformation?